# Whats wrong with my AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable, directive

To be able to watch the contents change for a `contenteditable` div or an `input` element, I have created the following directive:

```
app.directive('contenteditable',function() { return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        // view -> model
        element.bind('input', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(element["0"].tagName=="INPUT" ? element.val() : element.text());
                scope.watchCallback(element.attr('data-ng-model'));
            });
          });
        // model -> view
        ctrl.$render = function() {
            element.text(ctrl.$viewValue);
            element.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
        };
     }};
});
```

My Test Controller looks like:

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.singleVal = "X";
    $scope.multiVal = ["A"];
    $scope.addRow = function() {
        $scope.multiVal.push("");
    };
    $scope.watchCallback = function(modelName) {
        console.log(modelName+" was changed");
    }; 
}
```

When I test it against the following html, the singleVal (statically created) behaves well, but my multiVal (dynamically created using ng-repeat) doesnt. When I input a value, it just retains the original value (i.e the model is not getting refreshed). Please help.

```
<div data-ng-controller="TestController">
    <div contenteditable="true" data-ng-model="singleVal"></div>
    <button data-ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
    <table data-ng-repeat="val in multiVal"><tr><td>
        <div contenteditable="true" data-ng-model="val"></div>
    </td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind `ngModel` directly to a string in an array.  You'll need to store an array of objects inside of `multiVal`:

```
$scope.multiVal = [{property: "A"}];
```

Demonstrated here: **http://jsfiddle.net/YMJzN/**

Btw, you'll also want to adjust `$scope.addRow` to do the same...

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.multiVal.push({property:'new'});
}
```